# Problem with integration with indexed variable

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, variable, index

I wonder why I can not have a correct integration form on Mathematica with some indexed variables.

Indeed, when I write :

```
Integrate[r/Subscript[r, L], {r, 0, Subscript[r, L]}]
```

I have the following result :

[image]

However, when I write :

```
Integrate[r/Subscript[q, L], {r, 0, Subscript[q, L]}]
```

I obtain the expected (computed) expression :

[image]

Could you explain me where is my error ? and how can I have the expected result with first expression ?

Best,

Comment: @DanielHuber That's not quite the case, though close. `In[79]:= Integrate[q*Subscript[r, n], {Subscript[r, n], 0, q}]

Out[79]= q^3/2`. The issue with the one in this post is that `r` is the integration variable, and the integrand contains `Subscript[r, L]` which is viewed as an unknown function of `r`. So `Integrate` is flummoxed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this remark. But is it possible to prevent the problem ?
I would like to use rL as a variable in order to produce more clear formula, rather than using another variable name.

To summarize, is-it possible to constrain Mathematica to consider rL not as an unknown function but as a parameter independant from r ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to create an environment where subscripts are rendered inert, and then the expression is evaluated. For example:

```
SetAttributes[InactivatedSubscripts,HoldAll];

InactivatedSubscripts[expr_]:=Block[{CompressedData},
    With[{h=Hold[expr]/.s_Subscript:>RuleCondition@CompressedData[Compress@s]},
        ReleaseHold[h]
    ]
]
```

Then:

```
InactivatedSubscripts[
    Integrate[r/Subscript[r,L],{r,0,Subscript[r,L]}]
]
```

> Subscript[r, L]/2